# How is uvm_component registered inside the uvm_factory?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I've recently started studying the UVM and have some difficulty understanding the component/object registration process with the factory. Specifically, I can't find what line of code does the actual registration.

---

Here is my thought/search process:

1. I've found that `uvm_factory` class has a `register` method which registers a proxy object of a given type
2. This proxy object is of `uvm_component_registry` class parameterized with the type of the initially desired component/object
3. Inside `uvm_component_registry` class there is a `get` method, which creates the proxy object `me` and registers it with the factory via `factory.register(me)` call
4. In UVM Cookbook it says that every uvm_component should be registered with the factory by using the `uvm_component_utils` macro, which expands to the following code snippet:

   ```
   typedef uvm_component_registry #(T,`"S`") type_id;

   static function type_id get_type();
     return type_id::get();
   endfunction

   virtual function uvm_object_wrapper get_object_type();
     return type_id::get();
   endfunction

   virtual function string get_type_name ();
     return type_name;
   endfunction
   ```

---

So, here I come to the root of the problem. Inside the user class extended from the `uvm_component` class we have only the `uvm_component_utils` macro, which doesn't call the `get` method of the `uvm_component_registry`. Also there are no `get` method calls before the `build` phase during which we are creating the necessary class object using the factory. It certainly works, which means that our class has been registered. The question is - how? Are there some implicit `get` method calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary, because the `` `uvm_component_utils `` macro adds

```
typedef uvm_component_registry #(T,`"S`") type_id;
```

That parameterized class has a static variable with a declaration initialization

```
local static this_type me = get();
```

This calls `get()` without ever having to construct the `uvm_component_registry` class because it is a specialization of the class. You might want to read my DVCon paper: [Using Parameterized Classes and Factories: The Yin and Yang of Object-Oriented Verification](https://resources.sw.siemens.com/en-US/white-paper-using-parameterized-classes-and-factories-the-yin-and-yang-of-object), or watch my short course on [SystemVerilog OOP for UVM Verification](https://verificationacademy.com/courses/systemverilog-oop-for-uvm-verification). The go into detail how the UVM implements the Factory Design Pattern in [system-verilog](/questions/tagged/system-verilog)

Comment: thanks for a quick answer. It resolved the issue I had